# R subset function returns zero records, for unexplained reason

Tags: r

I must be missing something very basic.  Hope someone can point it out.  I'm trying to subset the following data frame based on a specific year and sex...

```
str(Bnames)
'data.frame':   258000 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ X.year.   : int  1880 1880 1880 1880 1880 1880 1880 1880 1880 1880 ...
 $ X.name.   : Factor w/ 6782 levels "\"Aaden\"","\"Aaliyah\"",..: 3380 6632 3125 1174 2554 2449 3428 6232 2834 5517 ...
 $ X.percent.: num  0.0815 0.0805 0.0501 0.0452 0.0433 ...
 $ X.sex.    : Factor w/ 2 levels "\"boy\"","\"girl\"": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

The code I have entered is

```
one <- subset(Bnames, X.year.==2008 & X.sex.=="boy") # I get zero rows returned

two<- subset(Bnames, X.year.==2008) # I get 2000 rows returned, which is correct

three <- subset(Bnames, X.sex.=="boy") # I get 0 rows returned

four <- subset(Bnames, X.name.=="John") # I get 0 rows returned
```

I don't understand.  I'm using a data set that is freely available at http://plyr.had.co.nz/09-user/

If I make my own data frame by repeat sampling of `c("boy","girl")`, the subset works fine.  Why is the code failing with the data that I started with?

Comment: It seems that the levels of your factor columns are quoted: for instance `X.sex.` column doesn't have `boy` or `girl` levels, but rather `"boy"`and `"girl"`. Try: `one <- subset(Bnames, X.year.==2008 & X.sex.=="\"boy\"")`

Comment: @nicola: You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @BondedDust Posted as answer. Thank you.

Comment: You can check the accuracy of nicola's diagnosis by typing `nchar("\"boy\"")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting 0 results is that the levels of your `factor` columns are quoted.  For instance, `X.sex.` column levels are not `boy` or `girl`, but rather `"boy"` and `"girl"`. This may due to the fact that the file you have imported your `data.frame` from had fields quoted and it was read through `read.table` (or some other equivalent function) with the `quote=FALSE` argument. If that's the case, you could easily re-read the file and correct this rather annoying feature.

Anyway, to proper subset your `data.frame` remember the quotes. For instance:

```
 one <- subset(Bnames, X.year.==2008 & X.sex.=="\"boy\"")
```

Alternatively, you may use the `'` as quote:

```
 one <- subset(Bnames, X.year.==2008 & X.sex.=='"boy"')
```

If you want to get rid of the annoying quotes without having to rebuild your `data.frame`, just try:

```
 Bnames[,4]<-factor(gsub(Bnames[,4],'"',""))
```

Comment: This worked but I had to move Bnames as seen in the following... Bnames[,4]<-factor(gsub('"',"",Bnames[,4])). Thanks